# Issue with Spring Helloworld Program

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I just started learning spring4. While trying to run my hello world program getting the following error,

```
Aug 22, 2015 9:37:17 AM org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@2b650cea: startup date [Sat Aug 22 09:37:17 IST 2015]; root of context hierarchy
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'helloWorldBean' defined in class com.websystique.spring.configuration.HelloWorldConfig: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorld com.websystique.spring.configuration.HelloWorldConfig.helloWorld()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorldImpl cannot be cast to com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorld
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:84)
    at com.websystique.spring.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:12)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorld com.websystique.spring.configuration.HelloWorldConfig.helloWorld()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorldImpl cannot be cast to com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorld
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:586)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorldImpl cannot be cast to com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorld
    at com.websystique.spring.configuration.HelloWorldConfig.helloWorld(HelloWorldConfig.java:16)
    at com.websystique.spring.configuration.HelloWorldConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c68b28f.CGLIB$helloWorld$0(<generated>)
    at com.websystique.spring.configuration.HelloWorldConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c68b28f$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$50c0f2d6.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:312)
    at com.websystique.spring.configuration.HelloWorldConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3c68b28f.helloWorld(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
    ... 14 more
```

My code is as follows,

**Config Class**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Description;

import com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorld;
import com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorldImpl;

@Configuration
public class HelloWorldConfig {

    @Bean(name="helloWorldBean")
    @Description("This is a sample HelloWorld Bean")
    public HelloWorld helloWorld() {
        return (HelloWorld) new HelloWorldImpl();
    }
}
```

**Interface:**

```
package com.websystique.spring.domain;

public interface HelloWorld {

    void sayHello(String name);

}
```

**Implementation Class**

```
package com.websystique.spring.domain;

public class HelloWorldImpl {

     public void sayHello(String name) {
            System.out.println("Hello "+name);
        }
}
```

**Main Class**

```
public class AppMain {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        AbstractApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(HelloWorldConfig.class);
        HelloWorld bean = (HelloWorld) context.getBean("helloWorldBean");
        bean.sayHello("Spring 4");
        context.close();
    }

}
```

Can any one tell me where is the error coming from and how to resolve the same.

Also can any one please suggest me the good blog or documentation to learn spring as early as possible..

Comment: Does this even compile? The cast doesn't sound right. Plus do you have the appropriate package names for the config class and the main class? I'm assuming you do but just checking to see if you missed them out by chance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorldImpl cannot be cast to
>   com.websystique.spring.domain.HelloWorld`

```
return (HelloWorld) new HelloWorldImpl();
```

To achieve this your `HelloWorldImpl` should implement `HelloWorld` than you even won't need to cast it to `HelloWorld`